# Access VBA string to return a Min & Max date based on matching criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use a string to get a minimum date from a field (`ExpectedTaskStart`) in a specified table
(`tblLiveTasks`) using a match on two ID fields (`CASEID`) from (`ExpectedTaskStart`) the other (`intCaseID`) I either get no return or a return of 0.  I have used various VBA outlined below but all with same outcome;

```vb
'Dim rsLiveCaseSpecific As DAO.Recordset, Var, strSQL As String
Dim rsDates As Recordset
Dim strSQLGetMINDate As Double
Dim strSQLGetMAXDate As Date
Dim MINDate As String
Dim MAXDate As String
Dim intCaseID As Long
Dim intCaseID2 As Integer

Let intCaseID = Forms![frmHome]![FRMHOMECASEID]

'----------------------------------------------------------
'Below here needs sorting

MsgBox "Done New Tasks"

Let strSQLGetMINDate = DateValue("SELECT DMIN(CDate ([tblLiveTasks].[ExpectedTaskStart]) FROM tblLiveTasks WHERE CaseID = " & intCaseID)

Let strSQLGetMAXDate = DateValue("SELECT MAX ([tblLiveTasks].[ExpectedTaskEnd]) FROM tblLiveTasks WHERE CaseID = " & intCaseID)

MINDate = Format(strSQLGetMINDate, "#dd/mm/yyyy#")

MsgBox (MINDate)
MsgBox "Done Date Value"

MINDate = Format(#1/1/2020#, "dd/mm/yyyy")
MAXDate = Format(strSQLGetMAXDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")'
```

I have also tried changing the code SELECT MAX to; DMIN/DMAX but still get no results.

Comment: See docs on [`DateValue`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) which does not process SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this reduced approach:

```vb
Dim SQLGetMINDate As Date
Dim SQLGetMAXDate As Date
Dim MINDate As String
Dim MAXDate As String
Dim intCaseID As Long

intCaseID = Forms![frmHome]![FRMHOMECASEID]
SQLGetMINDate = DMin("[ExpectedTaskStart]", "[tblLiveTasks]", "CaseID = " & intCaseID & "")
SQLGetMAXDate = DMax("[ExpectedTaskEnd]", "[tblLiveTasks]", "CaseID = " & intCaseID & "")

MINDate = Format(SQLGetMINDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: @Parfait: Coding style and preference only. Tells, that you haven't forgot something, and makes the criteria look similar to one concatenating a string or a date value.

Comment: This seems to do the trick I just need to figure something on the formatting as it returning the result as 4597dd/mm/yyyy4 - should I change the Date to Double in the Dim - or do you have another suggestion

Comment: Yes, see edited answer please. The octothorpes need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a stored query approach to retrieve values with `DLookUp` without any concatenation of SQL and VBA. Below requires form, `frmHome`, to be opened:

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT MIN([ExpectedTaskStart]) AS MinDate
     , MAX([ExpectedTaskEnd]) AS MaxDate
FROM tblLiveTasks
WHERE CaseID = Forms![frmHome]![FRMHOMECASEID]
```

**VBA**

```vb
...

MINDate = Format(DLookUp("MinDate", "mySavedQuery"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
MAXDate = Format(DLookUp("MaxDate", "mySavedQuery"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: I thought about this approach, we are trying to move away from queries to prevent errors when records being added at the same time

Comment: I do not understand how record appends prevents this solution. Query here will return latest saved entry.

Comment: Would the query still be able to run if it is already running? that seems to be the issue we have

Comment: I do not understand *already running*. Query here is a simple aggregate `SELECT` query on base table. Are you saying it does not return results or hangs in running? As noted, form, `frmHome`, must be opened.